# Why doesn't the mockAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce return any data

Tags: jestjs, axios-mock-adapter

Why doesn't the mockAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce return any data? I would like to see the errors.

```
  it('should show errors when submitting returns a 422 response', () => {
    mockAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        data: { errors: ['Name is required.', 'Email is required.'] },
        status: 422,
      })
    )

    addStudentForm()
      .find('button.open-modal')
      .simulate('click')
    addStudentForm()
      .find('button.submit')
      .simulate('click')

    expect(addStudentForm().instance().state.showModal).toBe(true)
    console.log(addStudentForm().instance().state)
  })
```

This is my state as it's there in the console.log.

```
{ showModal: true,
 name: '',
 username: '' }
```

On the frontend the response in `event.response.data` does show me what I want to see what I expect `errors :["Name is required.", "Email is required."]` but I cannot seem to mock it.

If you needed to see full context: [https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/classroom-mode/blob/mock-axio/client/src/**test**/AddStudentForm.test.js](https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/classroom-mode/blob/mock-axio/client/src/__test__/AddStudentForm.test.js)

Interesting enough when I have the await on the

```
await addStudentForm()
  .find('button.submit')
  .simulate('click')
```

The expect(addStudentForm().instance().state.showModal).toBe(true) returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to miss [done()](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html), and that's why test is finished earlier then mocked data returned:

```
it('should show errors when submitting returns a 422 response', done // < --HERE ->
=> {
    mockAxios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      Promise.resolve({
        data: { errors: ['Name is required.', 'Email is required.'] },
        status: 422,
      });

    addStudentForm()
      .find('button.open-modal')
      .simulate('click')
    addStudentForm()
      .find('button.submit')
      .simulate('click')

    expect(addStudentForm().instance().state.showModal).toBe(true)
    console.log(addStudentForm().instance().state);

      done(); // <- HERE ->
    })


  })
```